# TypeError: can't cast Array to json strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I have a rails 4 app with strong parameters like:

```
def product_params
   params.require(:product).permit(:title, :user_id, :info => [:color, :size])
end
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
INSERT INTO "products" ("created_at", "info","title", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Tue, 15 Apr 2014 01:30:31 UTC +00:00], ["info", [{"color"=>"Blue"}]], ["title", "Shoes"], ["updated_at", Tue, 15 Apr 2014 01:30:31 UTC +00:00]]
TypeError: can't cast Array to json: INSERT INTO "products" ("created_at", "info", "title", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"
```

Comment: This is not the problem with strong params but with your column type being json. See this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385023/cant-store-array-in-json-field-in-postgresql-rails-cant-cast-array-to-json

Comment: Which db you are using.